# UML diagram type for comunication between separate systems

Tags: uml

I want to draw an uml diagram for two systems that communicate through network.
It is similar to client-server scheme. Client send an event and server process it.
What kind of uml diagram should I use to do that? Components diagram?

Comment: Go through http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html and pick the type which is the closest to what you want

Comment: It depends on what you want to depict? The connection between those two, the message type sent back and forth, the order of the messages, the computers (more precisely nodes) and softwares?

Comment: I would like to depict connection between those two. I am writing documentation so uml is quicker to understand than a paragraph of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create component elements to represent your systems and than you can use sequence diagram to define how your systems communicate. For communicating system involved in interaction defined in sequence diagram use lifeline. Life line refers component of your system in this case. You can use collaboration diagram as well but sequence diagram is more powerfull for this purpose.